Tried to rotate a word in a table but a part of the word disappeared in LaTEX
It seems that my first part of the word "Pipe" is disappeared??
I use these packages
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{rotating}


    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{||>{\centering}m{1cm}| |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|>       

    {\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|>  

     {\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}||} 
        \rowcolor{gray!20}
        \hline
        Item & Outer \enspace diameter& Material & Standard & Description \\
        
        \hline\hline
    \rowcolor{white}
    \parbox[c][=0mm][r]{2mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{ \begin{turn}{90} Pipe
    \end{turn}}}&tekst1&&&\\&tekst2&&&\\
                 \hline
        1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
        2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\
        3 & 545 & 778 & 7507 \\
        4 & 545 & 18744 & 7560 \\
        5 & 88 & 788 & 6344 \\ [1ex] 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \end{table}
    \end{document}


I tried to rotate the word pipe in the table, but it somhow partly disappeared ???
How can I solve this

Please make sure that we can compile the code you show.
